# Web 2 /MVC 5 reuse of controllers

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-web-api

I have a WebAPI MVC App.  My routing for the api is /api/*** and works well.
I wish to implement several MVC Views and tried to put...

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";

        return View();
    }
```

...in my ApiController but Viewbag does not resolve.  I note that the HomeController is based on Controler (not ApiController).  Do I need to have a separate controller for my Views?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need a separate controller since MVC and WebAPI are two diferent ASP.NET technologies

[**Controller**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller) is for MVC. It relies on ActionResult to return a view or other types of results. **Actions that return ViewResult should use Controller**

[**ApiController**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.apicontroller) is WebAPI. It relies on serializing returned objects from actions.
**Actions that return objects to be automatically serialized to json/xml should use ApiController**

Although [This is going to change in MVC 6](http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/aspnet-vnext/overview)

> As part of ASP.NET vNext, the MVC, Web API, and Web Pages frameworks are being merged into one framework, called MVC 6. The new framework removes a lot of overlap between the existing MVC and Web API frameworks. It uses a common set of abstractions for routing, action selection, filters, model binding, and so on. You can use the framework to create both UI (HTML) and web APIs.